# Move two chars from string into another string goes wrong

Tags: c, c-strings

I have a simple c program what i want to do is to take first two numbers from string put it in another string which will be only these two numbers and then convert it to int.

strlen of hLength is 54...

```
char string[100] = ":50010000214601360121470136007EFE09D21901\n";
char hLength[3];
int length,c;

hLength[0] = string[1];
hLength[1] = string[2];

printf("%s", hLength);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Output now is "50:50010000214601360121470136007EFE09D21901"
But i want only "50"
And dont know where is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed to put the null character to end *hLength*, add

```
hLength[2] = 0;
```

you have your output because in your case *string* is after *hLength*, but this is a random effect of course

Comment: Ou thanks it works. But i dont know why. Still new in C. I tried to end string with hLength[2] = "\0" But it does not work and this works dont know why.

Comment: @JurajJakubov because `"\0"` is a string, not a char , you can use `'\0'`

Comment: I really want but there is time limit.

Answer (score 0):

`hLength[2]` is still unintialized. Unless it is populated with a null terminator, passing it to any function expecting a string parameter is undefined behavior.

While you could manually populate `hLength[2]` with zero, as you did with positions `0` and `1`, a more idiomatic way of doing this is use the library function `snprintf` with a limit of 2 characters on the source string:

```
snprintf(hLength, 3, "%*s", 2,  string);
```

Or even, at the declaration of `hLength`:

```
char hLength[3] = { string[0], string[1] }; // hLength[2] is initialized with a '\0' now
```

Note that implicitly filling the remainder of an array with zeroes is only valid if, at declaration, the array is *partly* initialized with curly braces as in `{ val1, val2 ... }`. Assigning individual elements of the array after declaration will not do this for you.